# i cant access to body from css

Tags: html, css

I've built this tribute page on Codepen. And I added Bootsrap. And then I cant access to body from css. You can check my code here.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: "Libre Barcode 39 Text";
  text-align: center;
}

.mainPicture {
  width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Text" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="header">Travis<span><img class="mainPicture" src="https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.398989678.9673/ap,550x550,12x12,1,transparent,t.u1.png"></span>Scott</h1>
```

Comment: did you try outside codepen ? as in codepen no need to have a body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap style is overriding your style. Use !important to override bootstrap style. For more details check these usages

```css
html>body {
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: "Libre Barcode 39 Text";
  text-align: center;
}

.mainPicture {
  width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Text" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="header">Travis<span><img class="mainPicture" src="https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.398989678.9673/ap,550x550,12x12,1,transparent,t.u1.png"></span>Scott</h1>
```

**Alternate Solution:-**

Use `html > body` to increase specificity which will be a good practice

```css
html > body {
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: "Libre Barcode 39 Text";
  text-align: center;
}

.mainPicture {
  width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Text" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="header">Travis<span><img class="mainPicture" src="https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.398989678.9673/ap,550x550,12x12,1,transparent,t.u1.png"></span>Scott</h1>
```